# How to access a C# Class library event from Silverlight application?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-4.0

Iam creating a application it is  a pub/sub model with silverligh as UI layer and C# class library which will read the rfid signal form a device and have to redirect to the UI and I have done this with a WCF Service layer.Now my requirement is have to eliminate the service layer and have to directly connect to the UI layer.So I have tried to change class library to silverlight class library but the supporting DLLs for the device driver are not build on the silverlight runtime.
Any Idea/Suggestion to access those methods.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using an RIA service?

Comment: seems like a good fit for what you need.  RIA generates code from a web project and compiles it for Silverlight.

Comment: @HaseebAkhtar: You need to **stop** making edits that introduce code tags in an inappropriate way (i.e. non-code)!